# Overwrote iPhone data by syncing to iTunes. Don't remember credentials of previous account. Any way to restore?

Tags: itunes, iphone

I connected the phone to the computer, trying to store some pictures, but the phone synced to my brother's account and all the contacts were overwritten.

I don't remember if I had any iCloud account or anything on my phone. Is there a way to restore the data that was there before syncing?

Comment: Did you do a backup of your iPhone via iTunes or to iCloud?  If so, you can use that to restore your phone.  If not, then no.